# Очистка окна ввода информации при переходе

Tags: javascript, vue.js, изображения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем привет,у меня есть вот такая страница,страница повреждений автомобиля,на ней пользователь добавляет данные о повреждении(фото,пометки) и нажимая на кнопку "далее",он переходит к следующему элементу списка.И вот вопрос ,как мне обнулять данные (т.е при переходе окошко становилось чистым) но предыдущие данные сохраняли,подскажите как такое можно сделать) также буду благодарен если подскажите как удалять изображение при клике на крестик) Если нужен код страницы,то вот

```
[![<template>
  <div class="main">
  <div>
    <menus></menus>
    <!--Лист с итемами-->
    <v-card class="elevation-4 mb-3">
      <div  class="item-container">
        <v-card
          v-on:click.native="fillDamages(component.id)"
          v-for="component in info.components"
          :key="component.id"
          tabindex="1"
          class="item">
          <h3>{{component.serialNumber}} . {{component.name}}</h3>
          <v-icon v-if="component.comment" class="icon-damage" color="green">check_circle</v-icon>
        </v-card>
      </div>
    </v-card>
    <!--Карточка справа-->
    <div class="main-info">
      <div v-if="selected">
      <v-layout class="info">
        <v-flex>
          <v-card class="info-car">
            <v-card-media
              class="white--text"
              height="80px"
              src="/src/assets/background.png">
              <v-container fill-height fluid>
                <v-layout fill-height>
                  <v-flex xs12 align-end flexbox>
                    <span class="headline">{{selected.serialNumber}} . {{selected.name}}</span>
                  </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
              </v-container>
            </v-card-media>
            <v-card-title>
              <div class="card-info">
                <span class="grey--text">
                  <h2>Фотографии</h2>
                </span><br>
                <!-- Блок фоток-->
                <div id="app" class="img-load">
                  <div v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="index" class="item-image">
                    <div class="img-container">
                      <img :src="item.url" alt="" v-if="item.url" @click="overallPopUp(index)" />
                      <img src="../assets/03.expert.inspection.photo.png" alt="" v-else/>
                      <img class="popUp" v-if="item.showPop" :src="item.url" v-click-outside="outOverallClick">
                      <v-btn class="btn-out" v-if="item.url" icon color="grey" small>
                        <v-icon color="black">clear</v-icon>
                      </v-btn>
                      <label class="loadfile" :class="{hide: item.url}">
                        <input class="inputfile" type="file" @change="overallFileSelected(index,'vin')">
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <span class="grey--text">
                  <h2>Тип повреждения</h2>
                </span><br>
                <!--Блок чекбоксов-->
                <div class="piker">
                  <v-checkbox
                  class="check-damage"
                  v-for="damage in info.damages"
                  :key="damage.id"
                  color="grey"
                  :label="damage.name">
                  </v-checkbox>
                </div>
                <span class="grey--text">
                  <h2>Комментарий</h2>
                </span><br>
                <v-form>
                  <v-text-field
                    label="Введите текст комментария"
                    v-model="message"
                    required>
                  </v-text-field>
                </v-form>
              </div>
            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-btn
                v-model="next"
                @click="nextDamage"
                class="btn-see"
                color="red">Далее</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import Menus from '../menus.vue';
import ClickOutside from "vue-click-outside";
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  components: {
    Menus,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: \[
        {leftFront: "", url: "", showPop: false}, {leftBack: "", url: "", showPop: false}, {rightFront: "", url: "", showPop: false},
      \],
      selected: null,
      selectedFile: null,
      message: '',
      url: null,
      current: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    fillDamages(num) {
      for(let ind in this.info.components) {
        if(this.info.components\[ind\].id == num) {
          this.info.components\[ind\].active = true;
          this.selected = this.info.components\[ind\];
          this.current = ind;
        } else {
          this.info.components\[ind\].active = false;
        }
      }
    },
      onFileSelected(event) {
        this.selectedFile = event.target.files\[0\];
        this.url = URL.createObjectURL(this.selectedFile);
      },
      overallFileSelected(i, str) {
        this.items\[i\]\[str\] = event.target.files\[0\];
        this.items\[i\].url = URL.createObjectURL(this.items\[i\]\[str\]);
      },
      overallPopUp(i) {
        this.items\[i\].showPop = true;
      },
      outOverallClick() {
        for(let elem of this.items) {
          elem.showPop = false;
        }
      },
    //Функция перехода к следующему элементу списка
    nextDamage() {
      let last = this.info.components.length - 1;

      this.info.components.find(item => {
        if (item.id === this.selected.id && this.message) {
          this.$set(item, 'comment', this.message);
        }
      });
      this.message = '';

      if (this.current < last) {
        this.info.components\[this.current\].save = true;
        this.current++;
        for (let comp of this.info.components) {
          comp.active = false;
        }
        this.info.components\[this.current\].active = true;
        this.selected = this.info.components\[this.current\];
      } else {
        this.info.components\[this.current\].save = true;
        this.$router.push('/infocar')
      }
    },
    onUpload() {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append(this.selectedFile.name, this.selectedFile);
      formData.append('name', 'files');
      this.$store.dispatch('loadFile', formData);
    },
  },
  computed: {
    info() {
      return this.$store.state.damages.info;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('setDamages')
  },
  directives: {
    ClickOutside
  },
};
</script>][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if="step === 1">
            <input type="text" v-model="form.step1.input">
            <button @click="handler1">NEXT</button>
        </div>
        <div v-if="step === 2">
            <input type="text" v-model="form.step2.input">
            <button @click="handler2">NEXT</button>
        </div>
        <div v-if="step === 3">
            {{ form.step1.input }}<br/>
            {{ form.step2.input }}<br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                form: {
                    step1: {
                        input : null,
                    },
                    step2: {
                        input : null,
                    }
                },
                step: 1,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            handler1: function(){
                //validate
                this.step = 2;
            },
            handler2: function(){
                //validate
                this.step = 3;
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: А можно ли пожалуйста на примере моего кода показать? Так немного не понятно,и без JQuery если можно:) Заранее спасибо)

Comment: @Jarvis, извеняюсь, сглупил, не посмотрев содержание вопроса. Переделал ответ под vue. К сожалению готовый код сделать не могу, т.к. нет времени на это, но из примера все должно быть понятно)

Comment: А может ли быть какая то другая реализация? у меня там 100+ элементов,и для каждого step писать я думаю будет некорректно

Comment: @Jarvis у вас 100 экранов менять нужно? один step - для 1 экрана, а в 1 экран ложите сколь угодно параметров и полей

Comment: На своем примере так и не смог реализовать....,может все таки поможете? На моей задаче

Comment: @Jarvis оберните свои окна в <div v-if="step === 1 или 2 или n">(окно)</div> и в нужный вам момент меняйте переменную step , vue сам все сделает

Comment: Ну можете показать пример на моем коде,буду очень благодарен)